# Can sqlite databae be used with as3 air app for android devices running 6.0+ versions?

Tags: android, sqlite, actionscript-3, flash, air

My App and Sqlite connection works on simulator but does not work when publishes on android device.

Below are the sample codes, I have tried, all work on simulator but not on android phone

```
 // SAMPLE-1
 var conn:SQLConnection = new SQLConnection();
 conn.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openSuccess);
 conn.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, openFailure);

 var fileLocation:File      =   File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("assets/weddingsql.sqlite"); ; 
 conn.openAsync(fileLocation, SQLMode.READ);    






  // SAMPLE-2
  var fileLocation:File         =   File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("assets/weddingsql.sqlite"); ; 
  var storageDbFilePath:File    =    File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("weddingsql.sqlite");
  fileLocation.copyToAsync(storageDbFilePath, true);
  fileLocation.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileCopiedHandler);

  function fileCopiedHandler(event:Event):void {
     trace("File Copied....");
     conn.openAsync(storageDbFilePath, SQLMode.READ);
  } 


 // Used in both the samples
 private function openSuccess(evt:SQLEvent):void{
    trace(" can not make connection to Database "); }

 private function openFailure(evt:SQLErrorEvent):void{
    trace(" can not make connection to Database ");}
```

And lastly, I suggest all as3 air developer to move on to native android if possible.

Comment: What error are you encountering?

Comment: In short - yes, it can. Do you get any traces when you debug the app ? Do you get any errors in the logcat? Does the database file already exist on the device? Because if not then the openMode for the connection should be SQLMode.CREATE.

Comment: On phone, it does not connect to database, Open Failure function is hit. but it works on simulator. I am using Animate CC and AIR SDK 21

Answer (score 0):

to use sqlite in android try add in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Yes, I have added that.