# AIR SQLite error with targetSdkVersion = 26

Tags: android, sqlite, actionscript-3, air

I have a mobile app (android/ios) that works great, but Google ask developers to use targetSdkVersion 26 now (mine was 19 so far).
And now that I use 26, I have an Error #3125 :

```
SQLError: 'Error #3125: Unable to open the database file.', details:'Connection closed.', operation:'open', detailID:'1001'
```

Here is my code to open the database :

```
static private function openDatabase(datebaseName:String) {

        sqlCon = new SQLConnection();           

        dbDir = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("ZANORG");
        dbDirFile = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("ZANORG/" + datebaseName + ".db");          

        if (dbDirFile.exists) {
            trace("File exists");
            sqlCon.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, onDatabaseOpen);
            sqlCon.open(dbDirFile);     // Error #3125 is here                      
        } else {
            trace("File does not exist");

            if (!dbDir.exists){
                trace("Folder doesn't exist > Create");
                try{
                    dbDir.createDirectory();
                }catch (error:Error){                       
                    trace("ERROR");
                    return;
                } 
            }
            sqlCon.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, onDatabaseCreationOpen);
            sqlCon.open(dbDirFile);             

            var strReq:String = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS gamedata (Score INT)";              
            sqlquery(strReq);


            strReq = "INSERT INTO gamedata (Score) values(0)";
            sqlquery(strReq);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103863/can-sqlite-databae-be-used-with-as3-air-app-for-android-devices-running-6-0-ver If no, then I still think it is a **permission** problem rather than code.

Comment: You may find this link helpful [SQLError #3125](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/578840) which has *This is expected behavior.  The database will not create folders on your behalf.  To fix this you just need to add some code to ensure that the directory is already present.  For example:

 
`File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("db").createDirectory();`*

Comment: I already tried these solutions, but no effect. I really don't understand why changing targetSdkVersion makes this bug !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for days I finally found the solution, it's a permission problem like Organis said..

I post my solution for anyone having the same problem, rather than calling my openDatabase function, I call this checkDatabase function :

```
private static function checkDatabase(databaseName:String){
        dbDirFile = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("ZANORG/" + databaseName + ".db");
        dbDir = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("ZANORG");

        if (File.permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.GRANTED){
            dbDir.addEventListener(PermissionEvent.PERMISSION_STATUS, function(e:PermissionEvent):void {
                if (e.status == PermissionStatus.GRANTED){
                    openDatabase(databaseName);
                }else{
                    // permission denied
                }
            });                  

            try {
                dbDir.requestPermission();
            }catch(e:Error){

                // another request is in progress

            }
        }else{
            openDatabase(databaseName);
        }       

    }
```